# Inverse of the function $f(x)=x-5x^2$ when $x\ge 1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse

[image: There i added the solution. Shouldn'that be added and subtracted but my prof has only added in the next step]

There I added the solution. Shouldn'that be added and subtracted but my prof has only added in the next step

Find the inverse of function $f(x)=x-5x^2$ when $x\ge 1$.

After completing the square somehow the signs don't match with the solution my professor did and it had me scratching my head.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to MSE community @Augustus Blake. Did you find expression for the inverse, i.e. for $f^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: Show us step by step what you did, and we can show you where you went wrong.  At the very least show us the result you have and what the supposedly correct result should be.

Comment: I added the solution. Did you catch it?

Comment: There i added the solution. Did you catch it?

Comment: Please add your solution via mathjax and don't use pictures.

Comment: You have $f^{-1}(y) = \frac {1 + \sqrt {1-20y}}{10}$ which is fine.  (I think your work is a little overcomplicated, but that is okay.)    If they have asked for $f^{-1}(x)$ then you just need to exchange the x and y.  $f^{-1}(x) = \frac {1 + \sqrt {1 - 20x}}{10}$ with $x \le -4$

Comment: @user376343  the vertex is at $x = \frac 1{10}$

Comment: @user317176 right, I've misread the expression.

Answer (score -1):

$$f(x)=x-5x^2, x\ge 1$$

Due to $x \ge 1$, if $x_1, x_2$ are solutions of $y=x-5x^2$, the larger one is the valid preimage.

From $y=x-5x^2$, let's solve for $x$.

$$5x^2-x+y=0$$

From the quadratic formula,
$$x=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-20y}}{10}$$

Hence, $$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-20x}}{10}$$

Comment: why is x>=1 makes the equation have only one solution?

Comment: it is a quadratic function with vertex at $\frac1{10}$, if $x > \frac1{10}$, then the preimage is the larger one, if $x < \frac1{10}$. then the preimage is the smaller one.